# Creating pandas series from array and list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to map array data to a list of column names

```
cols = list(X.columns)
a = log_reg.coef_
pd.Series(data=a,index=cols)
```

but keep getting this error message

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 32
```

This is a sample of the data in a

```
array([[-3.45917636e-04,  3.61924667e-01, -4.09270503e-01,
        -8.77365851e-01,  2.63110856e-01,  1.19371203e-01,
        -1.24971101e-01,  4.36160913e-01, -3.99315598e-01,
        -4.43522845e-01, -4.06608631e-01, -3.75995346e-01,
        -7.94023490e-02, -3.19954555e-01, -6.44072018e-01,
        -6.89515406e-01, -3.31630739e-01, -4.58094286e-01,
         1.17109079e-01,  2.28902301e-02,  1.74657944e-01,
         4.70689088e-01,  5.72027148e-01,  2.93303704e-01,
        -6.04354969e-03, -6.04084018e-01,  1.22102664e-01,
        -3.65628250e-02,  8.46421904e-02, -3.97469438e-03,
         1.05515634e+00, -6.57530123e-01]])
```

and the list of rows in cols:

```
['Time',
 'V1',
 'V2',
 'V3',
 'V4',
 'V5',
 'V6',
 'V7',
 'V8',
 'V9',
 'V10',
 'V11',
 'V12',
 'V13',
 'V14',
 'V15',
 'V16',
 'V17',
 'V18',
 'V19',
 'V20',
 'V21',
 'V22',
 'V23',
 'V24',
 'V25',
 'V26',
 'V27',
 'V28',
 'Amount',
 'Hours',
 'Fraudulent']
```

The endgoal is to create a series showing the coefficients of each feature (represented by the cols list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You array is having an array inside it. You have 32 column values, but your row array has a length of 1. As a result, your lengths of corresponding rows and columns don't match. What you need instead is the inner array which has a length of 32. You can access it using the index 0.

Therefore, try the following:

```
pd.Series(data=a[0], index=cols)
```

In case your array has further nested arrays inside, and you don't want to use multiple indices such as `a[0][0]` etc., you can flatten your array using either of the two options

```
pd.Series(data=a.flatten(), index=cols)
```

or

```
pd.Series(data=a.ravel(), index=cols)
```